# OpenLayers 3 circles with a distance-based radius

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to draw a circle on a map using OpenLayers. I would like to be able to define the radius of the circle in miles. Something like this:

```
function generateCircleFeature(lat,lng,radius_in_miles) {
    //clever stuff goes here
    //calculated_radius = some_function_of radius_in_miles

    var circle = new ol.geom.Circle(
            ol.proj.transform([lng, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            calculated_radius
    );

    var circleFeature = new ol.Feature(circle);
    return circleFeature;
}
```

I've searched and searched for a simple example that actually works, and am going slightly mad. All suggestions welcomed! Thanks :-)

Comment: Your question is answered here [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258456/openlayers-adding-circle-feature-with-same-vectorsource-increases-opacity-of-all] and the person who answered it also posted a link to a Fiddle environment with all his working code here[https://jsfiddle.net/1jzq6pLm/]

Comment: Thank you so much. I had found the post that HelpingHand refers to as the source for his or her circle function - and discovered that it wasn't working - so I am very grateful to you for this link. You've put a smile on my face, and it's not even 8am. Thank you :-)